# How do I display a hidden module from DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

Is it possible to display the module coming from a non-displayed state(hidden)? I have made a temporary solution where I close the previously opened module and then open it in display mode, but this can be extremely slow since it is opening the module twice:

```
// We actually get the mod from the object but you get what I mean
mod = fooFunc() // foo.inc
string modName = fullName(mod) // get module path
close(mod) // close hidden module
mod = read(modName, true, true) // open same module in "display" mode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`close` is not necessary.

```
Module mod = read ("/the/module", false, true)    
Object myObject = first mod
mod = read (fullName (module myObject), true, true)
```

works perfectly. I did not do any performance tests, but I don't think that making the module visible takes much time compared to opening it from scratch.

Comment: It is a better solution but after having taken a look at it I am pretty sure it just fully reloads the module since it takes the same time as re-opening it.

Comment: I cannot confirm this.  I have one module which takes some time to open.  Using `int ib = getTickCount_(); mod = read...; print (getTickCount_ - ib) "\n"`, I had the following results:
When module is closed, open visibly takes ca. 6000 milliseconds.
When I close it again and open it invisibly,it takes ca. 3000 ms.
Switching from invisible to visible also takes ca. 3000 ms. 
Also, I created a pre- open and a post-open trigger: switching from invisible to visible does not fire the triggers.
So, making the module visible does indeed take some time, but there are different actions performed

Comment: some hints on how to increase module load speed can be found here https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/forumsquestion?id=0D50z00006HILqGCAX&language=en_US, e.g. - purge soft-deleted objects
- baseline module
- delete unnecessary views
- reduce the number of links
- use default view for loading
- decrease the number of sections
- locate DXL code, e.g. in triggers

Comment: I decided to benchmark it as well and it seems you are partially right. Open visibly from closed state takes 2063 ms. Whereas making it visible from a invisible state takes around 1200-1500 ms(Something changes in-between runs?), so I guess you are right about it not opening from scratch. I expected it to be a bit faster but  I can use this. Thanks Mike.